# Response page not being scraped after POST_DATA - Beautiful Soup & Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage after posting data onto the form using the following code.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import requests
import webbrowser
import urllib.parse

url_for_parse = "http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx"
#PARSE THE WEBPAGE
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url_for_parse).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

#GET FORM ATTRIBUTES
form = soup.find('form')
action_value = form.get('action')
method_value = form.get('method')
id_value = form.get('id')

#POST DATA
payload = {'txtSearch':'HELLOWORLD'}
r = requests.post(url_for_parse, payload)

#PARSING ACTION VALUE WITH URL
url2 = urllib.parse.urljoin(url_for_parse,action_value)

#READ RESPONSE
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url2)
page_source = response.read()
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(page_source))

searchfile = open("results.html", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if "HELLOWORLD" in line: 
        print ("STRING FOUND")
    else:
        print ("STRING NOT FOUND")  
searchfile.close()
```

The code is right. The response web page is scraped successfully and stored in the results.html.

**However, I want to scrape the webpage after the post_data is executed. Because everytime I run the code I get the result : String Not Found.** Which means the resultant page is crawled before the post_data is executed.

***HOW TO MODIFY CODE SUCH THAT THE FORM IS SUCCESSFULLY SUBMITTED AND THEN THE SOURCE CODE IS STORED IN THE LOCAL FILE.?***

Is an alternate framework suggested instead of beautiful script for the above process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty obvious what you're doing.

```
1) You are posting some data to a URL
2) Scraping the same URL.
3) Check for some "String"
```

But what you should do.

```
1) Post data to a URL
2) Scrape the resultant page (Not the same URL) and store in the file
3) Check for some "String"
```

For this you need to write r.content to the local file and search for the string

Modify the code like this:

```
 payload = {'txtSearch':'HELLOWORLD'}
 url2 = urllib.parse.urljoin(url_for_parse,action_value)
 r = requests.post(url2, auth = {"USERNAME", "PASSWORD"}, payload)

  with open("results.html", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(r.content))

//Then continue searching for a String.
```

Note: You need to send the payload to url2 and not the initial URL (url_for_parse)

Answer (score 0):

The response that gets returned after your requests.post call will be the HTML you want to go through. You can access it by doing

```
r.content
```

However, with my test of this, it said that I hadn't authenticated, so I assume you've authenticated?

I would also recommend using requests entirely instead of using urllib for GETs and requests for POSTs.

Comment: I have tried r.content prior to the above code. The r.content snippet goes as follows:

#POST DATA
payload = {'txtSearch':'HELLOWORLD'}
r = requests.post(url_for_parse, payload)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(r.content))
However the same String not found result is the output.

Comment: Maybe it would help to visually parse through the page you POSTed to. When I tried to POST to the page, it told me I hadn't authenticated. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to persist your session parameters across your requests.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

```
import requests

proxies = {
    "http": "",
    "https": "",
}

headers = {
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {'item':'content'}
## not that you need basic auth but its simple to toss in requests
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('fake@example.com', 'not_a_real_password') 
s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
s.proxies.update(proxies)
response = s.post(url=url, data=data, auth=auth)
```

this key bit is really what you are invoking and then waiting for

```
<form name="cmt" method="post" action="comment.aspx">
```

which is just a post to http://demo.testfire.net/comment.aspx